# Relations-Equivalence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

A relation R is defined on the set of integers as $ (a, b) \in R $ if and only if $ a^2=b^2 $ then the relation R is

a)an equivalence relation
b)a partial ordering
c)a total ordering
d)None of the mentioned

I thought it as an equivalence relation but it seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Reflexive: $(a,a)\in R$

Symmetric: $(a,b)\in R \implies (b,a)\in R$

Transitive: $(a,b)\in R, (b,c)\in R \implies (a,c)\in R$

So it is an equivalence.